# CodeIgniter site's url is not working while in live

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

My developer recently had some negative argue with me and he has stopped working on my site anymore. I have shifted my site to a new web server and uploaded all the files by myself. (I really have poor idea with .php, WordPress, CodeIgniter).

Now the site is showing error like the below while I click in any link.

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL
>   /news/details/à¦°à§‹à¦¹à¦¿à¦™à§à¦—à¦¾à¦¦à§‡à¦°-à¦«à¦¿à¦°à¦¿à§Ÿà§‡-à¦¨à¦¿à¦¤à§‡-à¦®à¦¿à§Ÿà¦¾à¦¨à¦®à¦¾à¦°à§‡à¦°-à¦ªà§à¦°à¦¤à¦¿-à¦°à¦¾à¦·à§à¦Ÿà§à¦°à¦ªà¦¤à¦¿à¦°-à¦†à¦¹à§à¦¬à¦¾à¦¨
>   was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

how can I make the site live now?

my sites url: http://www.dhakagazette.net

the index now can be located at http://www.dhakagazette.net/.index.php

please suggest to make my site live.

Thank you

Comment: Make sure the new server configuration for .htaccess file first...

Comment: 1) Show htaccess and application/config/constants.php code. I will guide you.

Comment: Your URL Work when you add your site url is  http://www.dhakagazette.net to http://www.dhakagazette.net/.index.php

Comment: For your reference add `/.index.php` before `news` in your url

Comment: @DavinderKumar
I dont have any htaccess file in my root.

Here is my constat.php 
https://codepaste.net/giay9b

Comment: @Nawin  Thanks for the info that the /.index reloads my pages. But Can i make it automatic?

Comment: You have to debug code. For sure .htaccess will be here. How you are finding it? with FTP, .htaccess is by default hidden file you set it visible in FTP, if you are using cpanel then you set is visible too. Otherwise i have to look over the code. You can hire for that if you want. @shahan

Comment: Here is my htaccess found in /application/htaccess

https://justpaste.it/16up0
@DavinderKumar

Comment: Go to application/config/config.php and change your $config['index_page'] = dhakagazette.net/.index.php

Comment: No,it will be on root. You must hire a developer for this. Stackoverflow is for helping you get out of problem not for doing your job without a penny.